# Looping through a range. Copy if equals value. Runs but no results

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried using Offset to copy and paste plus about a million other things.  This used to have about ten ElseIf's that I commented out to try and simplify to help me figure out.  The only other thing I could think of is that I am having a brain cramp on this so any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub areax()

    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Rng4 As Range
    Dim Lr As Long

    For Lr = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 6 Step -1
        If Cells(Lr, "B") <> 0 Then

       If Cells(Lr, "B") = 6 Then
            Set Rng1 = Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row & ":I" & ActiveCell.Row)
            Set Rng2 = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Rng1.COPY Rng2
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Else
            If Cells(Lr, "B") = 12 Then
                Set Rng1 = Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row & ":J" & ActiveCell.Row)
                Set Rng2 = Range("K" & ActiveCell.Row & ":P" & ActiveCell.Row)
                Set Rng4 = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                Rng1.COPY Rng4
                Rng2.COPY Rng4
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        End If
        End If
    Next Lr

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it important to copy the range rather than just the values? You need the formatting as well or what is the point?

Comment: Also, you don't need to dim all the variables separately, you can just go `Dim Rng1, Rng2, Rng3, Rng4 As Range`

Comment: I only need the values, I just don't know how else to do it.  Thanks for the tip on the Dim

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in words with your data and I will give you a starter.  Also the way you have declared your variables (in VBA) is correct.  If you declare them as suggested by Steffen S N,  then only the last variable (Rng4 in your example) will be declared as Long.  The others on that line will be declared as Variant.

Comment: I have 9 rows of data across 45 col E6:aw14 (lets call this range x), outside range X col B contains the result of an index & match (based on a variable) to another worksheet. This is used to build a a grid within range x.  The grid can be up to 45 col wide, the width is determined for each row by the value of col B.  I need to rebuild the grid to be no more than 6 col wide. to accomplish this, I check the value of the cells in B, if = 6, I can just copy and paste the value into the next empty cell, if the value is 12, I have to copy and paste in two sections to the next empty cell.

Comment: Thanks sam axe.  Still a couple of Qs.  1.  Will col B always contain 9 rows (the same no of rows as the original 'grid' data.  If not, which rows in the grid should it draw from, when the values are 6 or 12?  2. Confirm that in the original grid data we will never be using data from cols Q to AW?

Comment: @Baarryleajo You are actually right, I have always thought that you were allowed to separate all of the same type by comma - but apparently not.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: @SteffenSylvestNielsen: `Dim Rng1, Rng2, Rng3, Rng4 As Range` doesn't do what you say. It is the equivalent of this: `Dim Rng1 as Variant, Rng2 as Variant, Rng3 as Variant, Rng4 As Range`. OP has it declared correctly. See [Chip Pearson site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @guitarthrower As you can see from my reply 2 hours before yours I have already commented on this.

Comment: Yes, always 9 rows.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @SteffenSylvestNielsen so you did! Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK sam axe - got to sign-out for this evening but try the code below.

From my last query comment to you, it assumes that col B has the same number of rows as the original data grid (9) and that we are only using columns E:J and K:P in the rebuilt grid.  If these are not the case then you can make some appropriate mods.

Also the following assumptions apply, again modify to suit your context:

Assumes grid data is in same sheet as col B

Assumes this sheet is called "Data"

Assumes rebuilt grid data starts at original data grid start col

I have used a few more variables so that you have got flexibility to easily change your output/layout etc.  I have also made two 'replacements' in your code.  1. replaced IF THEN construct with SELECT CASE construct which will allow you to add other conditions and 2. replaced your test for col B value being greater than 0 with a test for it being a numeric value.  It shouldn't then crash if a string accidentally creeps in.

@Steffen Sylvest Neilson has graciously acknowledged the Dim comment and has helpfully provided a link for you to perhaps explore.

May not be perfect for your needs yet, due to my lack of understanding, but as stated earlier, should be a good starter for you.

PS An explanation why you did not appear to be copying anything could be that ActiveCell may be selected outside your data.  ActiveCell doesn't follow your loop counter.

```
Sub areax()

Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
Dim lBrow As Long, lGridRow As Long, c As Long

Dim sdRow As Long, sdCol As Long
Dim gridsRow As Long, gridsCol As Long

'data start r/c
sdRow = 6
sdCol = 2

'grid start r/c
gridsRow = 6
gridsCol = 5

    With Sheets("Data")

    lBrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, sdCol).End(xlUp).Row

        'for each row in col B
        For c = sdRow To lBrow
            If IsNumeric(.Cells(c, "B")) Then
                'set next available row at bottom of grid
                lGridRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, gridsCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    'test col B cell value
                    Select Case .Cells(c, sdCol)
                        Case Is = 6
                            Set Rng1 = .Range(.Cells(c, "E"), .Cells(c, "J"))
                            Rng1.Copy Destination:=.Cells(lGridRow, gridsCol)
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False

                        Case Is = 12
                            Set Rng1 = .Range(.Cells(c, "E"), .Cells(c, "J"))
                            Set Rng2 = .Range(.Cells(c, "K"), .Cells(c, "P"))
                            Rng1.Copy Destination:=.Cells(lGridRow, gridsCol)
                            'add 1 to last grid row because of double-copy
                            lGridRow = lGridRow + 1
                            Rng2.Copy Destination:=.Cells(lGridRow, gridsCol)
                    End Select
            End If
        Next c

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't check this till Monday,  i should have brought my laptop home!  Thanks again!

Comment: OK, it's working!  However the data is being moved to the last row in Excel.  Debug.Print .Cells(lGridRow, gridsCol is returning 1048576 so I assume thats the problem.  I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I got it to work by doing this Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) I can't thank you enough!  If you had an idea of what was going wrong in this last part I would love to know.

Comment: Hello sam axe.  Glad you've got it working.  I can't reproduce the issue you have reported.  Check for a typo/completeness of the first  "lGridRow = ..." line within the loop.  I think the Application.CutCopyMode line in the Case = 6 section can also come out without affecting things.  Thank you also for marking as answer.